# What threat does the 1Password Browser authentication mitigate?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, browser-extensions

The latest 1Password browser update for Firefox includes an authorization between the plugin, and the browser itself.  This is documented on the vendors website: https://support.1password.com/browser-authorization/

What threat does this mitigate?

Comment: Looks like a way to ensure the browser extension is indeed from 1Password. A spurious extension would generate a different code.

Answer (score 1):

It's to prevent a second user logged into the same machine simultaneously with you, from asking your open password manager for login credentials by pretending to be a browser extension owned by you. Source: https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/70301/background-for-4-6-1-security-changes

This vulnerability was found by [Tavis Ormandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavis_Ormandy) of Google's Project Zero team, along with vulnerabilities in multiple other common password managers (some more severe).